# How to process 2 of click events in order in Angular

Tags: html, angular, events, click, inorder

```
<button class="post-save" (click)="fileUpload.upload()" (click)="editor.save()"> save </button>
```

When the save button is pressed,

Click Event 1 : File Upload

Click Event 2 : Post Save

When I click 'File Upload', it received the url as return value.

And 'editor.save()' is 'save the return url'.

So I want to run 'Event 2' after 'Event 1' is over.

How can I fix it?

Comment: if `fileUpload.upload()` is asynchronous, and I'm pretty sure it is, you're asking the wrong question my friend.

Comment: Can you post code for how the fileupload.upload() method returns the value. I suspect you are either going to get an observable and have to subscribe or wait until a promise is completed before running the second method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call one function only. I suspect `fileUpload.upload()` to be async, so one way to do it would be :

```
newFunction(){
    this.fileUpload.upload().subscribe(data => {
      // do what you do when the file is uploaded
      this.editor.save();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can call two or more methods in any event using by separting semicolon **;**

like this,

```
<button class="post-save" (click)="editor.save(); fileUpload.upload()"> save </button>
```